# Get which locales have their own values folder

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

I'm implementing multiple language support for my application. For now in my default `values` folder I have strings for english locale. I also have a folder for swedish `values-sv`.
I want to let the user to be able to choose the locale manually, for that I need to display a list with supported languages.

Is there a way to get which locales are supported(have their own values folder)?

So far I have:

> String[] languages = getResources().getAssets().getLocales();

But this returns all the languages that are supported by this Android version but it does not make sense to show that long list. I only need the languages supported by my application.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your You can show a spinner/dialog chooser to user with items of supported languages that you have and can tell your app which resources you have to select

Suppose if you have spanish and englih language:

show a spinner with values i.e: Spanish,English
the upon user selected value set the Locale to Spanish Or Either English

Comment: So you want to change the App language when device locale is Changed from settings ?? am i right ??

Comment: No, changing the application language from system settings works just fine. I want to let the user overwrite the language from the application.

Comment: Unable to understand your requirement "want to let the user overwrite the language from the application" doesn't that mean you ask user which language to show ??

Comment: That's correct, I want to let the user choose the language from within the app, not from android settings.

Comment: then the only way is to let the user give something to choose which language he wanna select am right ??

Answer (score 0):

Hardcode it.

Or, write a script that generates a snippet of Java code based on what is in your `res/values/` directory, and integrate that script into your build process. This may be easier with the new Gradle-based build system as it moves towards release status.